# Can't invoke method in class' "this" method

Tags: scala

I'm running into

```
error: not found: value defineParser
[scalac-2.11]   def this(format: String) = this(format, defineParser(format))
```

when I try to call a method in the `this` method of a class in order to dynamically return a parser depending on the format.

The class entire structure looks like so:

```
class TimestampConversion(format: String, parser: DSVTimestampFormatter) extends ObjectConversion[Any] with FormattedConversion[DSVTimestampFormatter] {

  def defineParser(format: String): DSVTimestampFormatter = {
    // hidden implementation details
  }

  def this(format: String) = this(format, defineParser(format))
}
```

And this fails on compiling this class. Why am I not able to invoke the `defineParser` method? It's well defined there.

Comment: It is really not _"defined"_ there. That method is part of the class definition. So, it does not make sense to call such method, because it depends on an instance of the class to be called, instance that at that time is not already instantiated. Thus it is not safe to call it, because it may depended on the state of the instance.... If the method could _(and should)_ be `static` in java, meaning it does not depend on the state of the instance, then you may move it to an **object**, probably the **companion object** of the class, and call it like this `objectName.defineParser(format)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to define a secondary constructor, but it's slightly more idiomatic to add `apply` factory methods to the companion object instead.

It's also possible to add a default arg for the parameter in the primary constructor, where it's more obvious what the scope is:

```
class C(format: String)(parser: Parser = C.defineParser(format))
object C { private def defineParser(format: String): Parser = ??? }
```

Here is the spec language (section 5.3.1) saying that the scope for your `this` invocation is not "inside the braces of the class definition":

> The signature and the self constructor invocation of a constructor
>   definition are type-checked and evaluated in the scope which is in
>   effect at the point of the enclosing class definition, augmented by
>   any type parameters of the enclosing class and by any early
>   definitions of the enclosing template. The rest of the constructor
>   expression is type-checked and evaluated as a function body in the
>   current class.